# I am trying to skip the Payment Address in checkout page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

In the checkout process, I am trying to hide the second step which is *Payment address*. My solution is to invoke the delivery address first then use the same address to save the data for the payment address as well using ajax post method.

But I am getting an error in the ajax post method for the `index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/save`

I have tried to make the payment_address/save POST call inside the `#button-shipping-address` click function, but it's not working.

```
// Shipping Address
...
$(document).delegate('#button-shipping-address', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'text\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'date\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'datetime-local\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'time\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'password\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-shipping-address textarea, #collapse-shipping-address select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-shipping-address').button('loading');
        },
        success: function(json) {      
            $('.alert-dismissible, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                $('#button-shipping-address').button('reset');

                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">' + json['error']['warning'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }

                for (i in json['error']) {
                    var element = $('#input-shipping-' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                    if ($(element).parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                        $(element).parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
                    } else {
                        $(element).after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
                    }
                }

                // Highlight any found errors
                $('.text-danger').parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            } else {

            //****** start payment address

                                $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'text\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'date\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'datetime-local\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'time\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'password\'], #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-shipping-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-shipping-address textarea, #collapse-shipping-address select,collapse-shipping-address label'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            //$('#button-payment-address').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            //$('#button-payment-address').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(jsons) {
            console.log('sent payment add'+JSON.stringify(jsons));
        }
    });

                            //******* end of payment call

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
```

This does not work, no data is saved to "/payment_address/save". Generally it should give a null array response ([]) something like this but its giving the error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "firstname": "First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!",
        "lastname": "Last Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!",
        "address_1": "Address 1 must be between 3 and 128 characters!",
        "city": "City must be between 2 and 128 characters!",
        "custom_field1": "Mobile required!"
    }
}
```

I have been working on it for the past 2 days but can't find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the correct data? The information you are passing under the Ajax.data seems incorrect. You probably need to use `.serialize()`. I suggest you move that to its own variable first that you can test, instead of `$('loooooooong string....')`

Comment: Yes my friend i am sending the same data for both the calls and its correct, i have confirmed this by calling the  **index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address/save** and i got no error when calling the **shipping_address/save** and gave me this response as well"[]"

Comment: I suggest to look at OC marketplace... for example: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=skip%20checkout%20steps There you'll find what you need and not very expensive. You'll buy cheap lesson for you for the future. I mean you'll find there the code, which let you to understand how it working in OC framework.

Comment: @K.B. Thanks for that link but it doenst matter if its cheap or expensive i am trying to fix the problem i know doing right but i am stuck in this problem there could be a minor fix for this problem . And what is the point of raising the question on stackoverflow when you can buy the modules :D

Comment: OK. I think you can't achieve this in your way, because shipping_address data are not populated yet, before you not on the shipping_adress step, I mean all fields are empty. Maybe you need create some function in controller checkout.php  where you invoke shipping_address data from DB and call it in ajax. Simplest way to hide 3 step.. and your solution should work.

Comment: @K.B. Good idea let me try that, i will keep the billing address visible and will try to hide the shipping address.

Comment: @K.B. Lol now the payment address is working fine and returning no error but  getting the same error in `route=checkout/shipping_address/save ` 

error:
`{"error":{"firstname":"First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!","lastname":"Last Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!","address_1":"Address 1 must be between 3 and 128 characters!","city":"City must be between 2 and 128 characters!","custom_field1":"Mobile required!"}}`

Comment: You should use data from payment_address. This data already populated to the fields and are posted.

Answer (score 2):

working solution to hide 3 step on OC3.0.x:
in file catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_address.php somwhere after `$this->load->language('checkout/checkout');` add:

```
if (!empty($this->session->data['shipping_address']['address_id'])) {
    $this->session->data['shipping_address']['address_id'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['address_id'];
}
```

After that you need to skip 3 step to go forward.
in file: catalog/view/theme/your_template/template/checkout/shipping_address.twig
add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    if ($('#shipping-address-clicked').length == 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#button-guest-shipping').click();
            $('#button-shipping-address').click();
            $('body').append('<div id="shipping-address-clicked" />');
                                }, 500);
                            }
        $('#button-guest, #button-register, #button-payment-address, #collapse-payment-address').click(function(){
        $('#shipping-address-clicked').remove();
        });
   //--></script>
```

after that you need to hide this step using css
in file catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/checkout/checkout.twig
add  style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #accordion > div:nth-child(3)  {
        display: none;
        }
   </style>
```

and also hide checkbox using style and add value 1 if shipping is required in files:
catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/checkout/guest.twig
catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/checkout/register.twig 
find: `{% if shipping_required %}`
 add after:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping_address" value="1" checked="checked" style="display: none" />
{% else %}
```